# Partitioning to enable dual boot windows 7 and ubuntu reinstall

Tags: dual-boot

I have decided to shrink my hdd by 30GB to facilitate a Win 7 and 11.04 dual boot. The 30GB partition will sort of be my permanent ubuntu partition. My question is when installing 11.04 on the 28th, how many sub-partitions are needed in the 30GB to enable a reinstall if the need arises (swap, ubuntu data & settings)? Should the 30GB be primary or logical? I have 4GB ram how much swap size is needed? Please help a newbie who simply loves UBUNTU!

Comment: It has been said that the recommended amount of swap space is twice your RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that your hdd is currently being taken up by Windows 7 and you are wanting to do a dual-boot and want Ubuntu to take up 30GB.

The easiest way to do this, is to have Windows 7 installed first, and then install Ubuntu. When you start the install, it will specifically ask if you want to shrink Windows and add Ubuntu alongside. Choose that option, and it will let you specify how big you want the Ubuntu partition. In your case, set it to 30GB and it will do all of the work for you.

Answer (score 1):

For shrinking and doing all sort of things you can use Easeus partition master.you can download it at

> http://download.cnet.com/EaseUS-Partition-Master-Home-Edition/3000-2248_4-10863346.html

Even you can boot into livecd installer use gparted partition manager.

You can use easyBCD software to dual boot,please follow this guide

> http://neosmart.net/wiki/display/EBCD/Ubuntu

Most of the times it will work,sometimes this may not work.In that case you can follow this article

> http://www.iceflatline.com/2009/09/how-to-dual-boot-windows-7-and-linux-using-bcdedit/

the second method is somewhat complex but it works for sure,I used both methods.